# Not all Latin and Greek characters are displayed using Polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, greek

For my thesis I need to write words in different languages and so I use the `polyglossia` package, but I just noticed that some of the Latin and Greek characters are not showing, like latin upsilon.

What do I have to do to make this characters appear?

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{tasks}     

\usepackage{tabularx}    

 \usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{slantsc}     

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek}      

\usepackage{polyglossia}     
\setmainlanguage{french}    
\setotherlanguages{english,german,italian,latin,spanish,russian}    

\begin{document}    
En protoroman, ce suffixe est productif presque uniquement sur le radical du participe parfait des verbes : */'kʊnsu-e-/ > */kʊn'sut-u/ > */kʊnsu't-ur-a/, */'Φrig-e-/ > */'Φrikt-u/ > */Φrik't-ur-a/ ; */'ard-e-/ > */'ars-u/ > */ar's-ur-a/, */'klaud-e-/ > */'klaus-u/ > */klau's-ur-a/. Dans quelques rares cas, il s'agit d'une resuffixation d'un lexème dérivé en */-'or-e/ : */ka'l-or-e/ > */ka'l-ur-a/, */orri'd-or-e/ > */orri'd-ur-a/. \\    
Le cas de */derek't-ur-a/ semble de prime abord être une exception, la base dérivationnelle étant un adjectif, */de'rekt-u/. Cependant, */de'rekt-u/ est en même temps la forme du participe passé du verbe correspondant */de'rig-e-/, ce qui fait entrer cette dérivation dans le giron  de la série régulière des dérivés nominaux en */-'ur-a/.\\    
En ce qui concerne les dérivés */ka'l-ur-a/ et */orri'd-ur-a/, il est curieux que le suffixe */-'ur-a/ paraît avoir semblé à un certain moment plus adéquat aux locuteurs que le suffixe */-'or-e/, mais que les deux ont cependant eu un destin tout à fait distinct : dans le premier cas, */ka'l-ur-a/ a été évincé par */ka'l-or-e/, tandis que dans le deuxième cas, */orri'd-ur-a/ a finalement évincé */orri'd-or-e/. \\    

En ce qui concerne le sémantisme, autant en pré-protoroman qu'en protoroman, le suffixe */-'ur-a/ désigne généralement une action et son effet : 

\begin{itemize}     
    \item */kʊnsu't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de coudre ; assemblage de deux morceaux d'étoffe cousus ensemble, couture »     
    \item */Φrik't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de cuire certains aliments à la poêle, le résultat de la cuisson »     
    \item */mʊli't-ur-a/ s.f. « action de moudre une céréale ; revenu qu'obtient le meunier pour la céréale moulue »     
    \item */ordi't-ur-a/ s.f. «  le résultat de l'ourdissage ; structure ; longueur de la chaîne d'une étoffe, ourdissage »      
\end{itemize}     

\end{document}
```

The text displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `fontspec` and therefore `xelatex` (or `lualatex`), you need to specify a font. You can choose one from your own OS that you know supports all the glyphs you're going to have in your thesis.

This is an example with `Linux Libertine O`, but you can pick any font as long as it's in your own system. Add it using `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}`, for example.

[image]